# Javascript - Drag and clone Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, draggable

Sorry I'm a newb at this ... looking to click on a picture and drag it into another div but keeping the original picture in the same position and state. 
I had a go at this but failed! Thanks in advance for the help.

```
      <div id="#user3profile" >
          <img src="pic/user3.png" class="userprofilepic" id="userprofile3" width="88" height="70">
      </div>

      <script>
           $(".userprofilepic").draggable({ helper: 'clone'});
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using jquery UI api to solve drag and drop. Take a look my example and change the style html that you wanted.

**HTML**

```
<br><br>

<table class="original" id="diagram">
    <tbody id="sortable2">
   <tr class="new-item"> 
       <td><img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/beauty-and-the-beast-trailer.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1" alt="disney" /></td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<br><br>

<table class="clone" id="diagram1" >
    <tbody id="clonetable">

     </tbody>
</table>

 <br><br>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
}

.original tbody tr.test2 td {
    background: rgba(20, 111, 186, 0.38);
}

img {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#clonetable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
$(".new-item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#clonetable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 10000
});
```

[FULL DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fn436n49/embedded/result/)

Comment: Thank you so much.. your a star ... great pic you have used!! hahaha Disney fan ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove # from the div id, modify . to # from the jQuery Code.

Comment: Hi Kang-Jun Heo :), thanks ! :) brains half asleep, the clone part still not working :(

Comment: @stevenpjm ***double check it*** - it should work. Check it again and again. Also try viewing the console window for any error. Make a simple demo to see it working ***independently***. That's called ***divide to conquer***. Your initial mistakes are almost ***unbelievable***. So it's just easy to keep believing that you still have something wrong elsewhere

Comment: @stevenpjm try this https://jsfiddle.net/z6j0s9nx/ isn't this what you want? You can drag a cloned *image* of the img (not sure if you want to drag the div or the img, but from your code it is the img).